# Does ios simulator run on Mac OS X Server?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-server

Which versions of Mac OS X Server will the iOS Simulator run on, if any?
I'm asking about OS X Server, not the normal OS X.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that it doesn't?  I assume that if you install the usual developer tools on OSX Server that the simulator and all the rest would run fine, but I haven't tested.

Comment: I have no particular reason to think that it does or doesn't, but I need to find out before I install a new operating system.  If you do test, feel free to add that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have a mac mini running  Mac OS X Server Lion 10.7.4  and  I've been testing on iOS simulator for last 2 months no problem.

Comment: I guess that's all one needs to hear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I marked it as right, is there any way to give you the full karma even though I marked it after the deadline?  (I only check SO once every day or two so I missed doing so before the deadline)

Answer (score 3):

OS X Server was never any different than OS X "client" except for bundled apps and services. With Lion and Mountain Lion (you probably want the latest Xcode so you will need one of those), OS X Server is just an additional installer from the AppStore and installing it by no means prevents you from installing or running any developer tools.